# Parsing Error: Unexpected token "" at EOF in a basic react .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When compiling a simple react app, I get an error saying "Unexpected Token" on the last(blank) line of the file

```
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';


class Companies extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var user = null;
        if (props.hasOwnProperty("user")){
            user = props["user"];
        }
        this.state = {
            user: user,
            companies: [],
        };
    }

}

export Companies
```

Is the code I'm attempting to run

```
Failed to compile.

./src/Companies.js
  Line 22:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  20 |
  21 | export Companies
> 22 |
     | ^
```

is the error message I am receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export a class the correct syntax is: `export default Class`

Try this:

```
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';


class Companies extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var user = null;
        if (props.hasOwnProperty("user")){
            user = props["user"];
        }
        this.state = {
            user: user,
            companies: [],
        };
    }

}

export default Companies
```